# how to select all users from the branch where the logged in user is the branch head

Tags: php, mysql

### |#id|user_id|branch_id|relationship|staus|

### |01| 203002 |10000005|     client|  active |

### |02| 200102 |10000005|     client|active|

### |03| 770002 |10000005|br_head|active|

### |04|  770002 |20000005|     br_head|active|

### |05| 230002 |20000005|     client|active|

### |06| 930002 |20000005|     client|active|

there is one table which holds relationship between users(customer, staff) and branchs which is called RELATIONSHIP_TABLE, in my app there is a page called clients which displays all users who has relationship with the branch, where the logged_in user also has relationship

logged_in user_id = 770002
when i query i must get 
must get back #1,#2,#5,#6 's user_id

```
my working code is this:
$sql = "
select branch_id 
from relationship_table 
where user_id='$logged_id_user'";
$reslut_set = $database->query($sql);

while($result = $result_set->fetch()){
    $sql_2 = " 
    SELECT user_id FROM relationship_table 
    where branch_id='{$result['branch_id']}'";
    $reslut_set2 = $database->query($sql_2);

    while($reslut_2 = $result_ser_2->fetch()){
        echo full_name($result_2['user_id']);
    }
}
```

but i dont want to loop to get this data 
can anybody suggest me better way of querying

I am new to sql and php so please guide me in proper direction 
thanks for answer

Comment: what is the problem? no result ?? any error??? explain more clearly

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Comment: More over, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: i am using pdo so i dont think my sql is vulnerable

Comment: thanks for the person who gave me -1 without even explaining why it an worthless question if its possible could you please explain me whats wrong with my qustion

Comment: For the reason, please refer to my comment above. Downvotes do not necessarily mean the question is "worthless"; it means "the question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" (to cite the downvote button's tooltip). Your question is too localized, and is unlikely to help anyone else in the future. Also, SO is not a debugging site, and we don't even know what is "the desired behavior, [the] specific problem or error" and you also don't have any code we would need to reproduce the issue. Thus, I believe I have explained myself quite clearly.

Comment: Your code *is* vulnerable to SQL injection, by the way, in the last line, where you are using `$loggedin_user` directly. As you are using PDO, you could have used prepared queries instead.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, i am new to sql and i realiy wanna slove this problem, will you help me please @LéoLam

Comment: I'm sorry but I really **can't** help you further; with all due respect, I would suggest reading more about [preventing SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) instead and before someone can help you, you'll have to clarify your question.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion , and now i have re framed my question any suggestion will help and sorry to bother you @LéoLam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct 
        r1.user_id FROM relationship_table r1 
        RIGHT JOIN relationship_table r2 
        ON r1.branch_id=r2.branch_id 
        WHERE r2.user_id='".$user_id."' 
        AND NOT r1.user_id=r2.user_id";
```

with this sql i was able to achive what I was looking for.

Comment: Warning: **Vulnerable to SQL injection.**